# MuleSoft: Can we customize API Toolkit RAML Schema Validation ?

Tags: mule, raml, mule-esb

I am new in mulesoft, I am trying to use RAML for schema validation, Problem is when we received bad request which is not as per schema, APIToolkit will throw exception one by one against the individual field.

Is there any way, using which we can override existing schema validation code with our in APIToolkit?

At the end i want to give all attributes from Request which has an error, and not as per schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `disableValidations` on the `apikit:router` which will disable incoming requests. Then you can create your own validation logic to create the response you desire.